# Colorful dropdown in Wicket

Tags: select, colors, wicket

Is it possible that add colorful items in dropdown in Wicket? Dropdown will take its values from enum class.
For example, enum class has 'red,yellow,green' elements. Sections of dropdown will be green, red, yellow colors according to element.
How can i make that?
Is it possible to use an AttributeModifier on the DropDownChoice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://examples8x.wicket.apache.org/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.SelectPage

Select component is more flexible than DropDownChoice, but it also consumes more memory due to the usage of a SelectOption component for each <option>.

Comment: Original link was broken. To navigate to the SelectPage example more generically you man go to http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples then choose _compref_ and _wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.select.Select_.

Answer (score 2):

try this.....

```
<style type="text/css">
    OPTION.red{color:red}
    OPTION.yellow{color:yellow}
    OPTION.green{color:green}
</style>

<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1" class="red">red</option>
    <option value="2" class="yellow">yellow</option>
    <option value="3" class="green">green</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I need it to be database driven so this will not go :(

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, detailed [on the wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/how-to-modify-an-attribute-on-a-html-tag.html), to dynamically add or change an attribute on an html tag at the time it is rendered.